# Go function accept different array parameter

Tags: go, interface

I want to use a generic function to unmarshal different types:

```
type Foo struct {
  Name    string
  Another string
}

type Bar struct {
  Name  string
  Some  string
}

func unmarshal(data []byte, val *[]map[string]interface{}) {
  err := json.Unmarshal(data, val)

  if err != nil || (*val)[0]["Name"] == "" {
    *val = nil
  }
}

func main() {
  var foos []Foo
  var bars []Bar

  // fooData and barData are JSON strings retrieved from database
  unmarshal(fooData, &foos)
  unmarshal(barData, &bars)
}
```

I got an error like `cannot use &foo (type *[]Foo) as type *[]map[string]interface {} in argument to unmarshal`.

I've tried use `val interface{}` as the parameter but it doesn't support index.

How can I achieve the goal then? Thanks.

Comment: The compiler tells you, that you're passing a _pointer to a slice of `Foo`_, but the function expects _a pointer to a slice of `map[string]interface{}`_. That's clearly not gonna work because a `Foo` is not a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with arbitrary slice types, declare the argument as type `interface{}` and use [reflection](https://godoc.org/reflect) to access the value:

```
func unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, v)
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()

    if err != nil || rv.Len() == 0 || rv.Index(0).FieldByName("Name").Interface() == "" {
        rv.Set(reflect.Zero(rv.Type()))
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. One more thing, if the field name doesn't exist, the code will panic by `panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value`. How can I do some precheck to make the code stronger?

Comment: Check that value returned from FieldByNsme is valid before calling Interface. https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.IsValid